# unable to move file to the wastebasket permission denied

Tags: raspbian

I am working on Raspberry pi and i am trying to delete a file but it is not working and it is giving me this error

```
unable to move file to the wastebasket permission denied
```

Comment: how are you trying to delete a file? Drag and drop on the desktop?

Comment: Is this file on an external device like a USB key or hard drive?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is that you are attempting to delete a file in a protected folder. If you are doing this via terminal you can simply place sudo infront of your command and it will run the command as root. If you are using the RPi inbuilt file manager, you can simply navigate on the top menu button thingy: tools > Open current folder as root. Viola. I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar problem removing an Arduino icon from /usr/share/applications. Here is what I did.

1) Use the file manager to navigate to the folder that contains the file you 
   are trying to delete. (The file location should be in the error message)

2) Tools>Open Current Folder in Terminal <kbd>F4</kbd>

3) Type `ls` in terminal to display a list of files in that folder.

4) Confirm that the file you want to delete is there.

5) Type `sudo rm [file name, as it is displayed in the list]` (rm = remove)